# How to create callback page for oauth with nextjs with a django grapql backend

Tags: django, next.js, oauth-2.0, graphql, next.js13

I'd like to give some context to the setup I have going on. I'm creating a software web application and below is the setup:

- Backend - Django with a GraphQL API using graphene.
- Frontend - NextJS (/app directory) with Apollo GraphQL to speak to the backend.

My app will allow users to link their accounts to eBay using [OAuth](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html). I have attached how I envisage my flow working:

[image: OAuth Flow]

The issue I am running into is on the `/ebay-callback` page. It is making multiple calls to the GraphQL API and then for some reason it fails redirect as the compiler fails (although not sure if the compiler issue is actually related).

The code for my callback page is as follows:

```js
'use client'

import { gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const INITIATE_OAUTH_GET_ACCESS_TOKEN = gql`
mutation InitiateOauthGetAccessToken($name: String!, $code: String!) {
    initiateOauthGetAccessToken(code: $code, name: $name) {
        success
        ebayAccount {
            id
        }
    }
}
`;

export default function EbayCallbackPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();

    const [initiateOauthGetAccessToken] = useMutation(INITIATE_OAUTH_GET_ACCESS_TOKEN);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleOAuth = async () => {
            console.log(searchParams);

            const code = searchParams.get('code');
            const state = searchParams.get('state');

            console.log(code);
            console.log(state);

            try {

                const { data } = await initiateOauthGetAccessToken({
                    variables: { code: code, name: state }
                });

                if (data.initiateOauthGetAccessToken.success) {
                    console.log("Login success:", data.initiateOauthGetAccessToken.ebayAccount);

                    const ebayAccount = data.initiateOauthGetAccessToken.ebayAccount;

                    router.push(`/dashboard/${ebayAccount.id}`);
                } else {
                    //router.push('/not-found');
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

        handleOAuth();
    }, []);

    // Since the page is just for processing and redirecting, no actual rendering is needed
    return (
        <div>
            searchParams: {JSON.stringify(searchParams)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Is my callback page set up incorrectly?